# toggling a pin using the hardware compare feature of timer1 AVR

Tags: avr, i2c, timer, interrupts

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599618/avr-timer-programming-ctc-mode-vs-normal-mode) - says:

> "In CTC mode, you can also trigger interrupts, but it is also
>   possible to not use interrupts and still toggle an output pin. Using
>   it this way, the functionality occurs **parallel to the CPU and
>   doesn't interrupt anything.**"

(emphasis mine)

We are trying to use the main while loop in our AVR program to talk to an I<sup>2</sup>C device, while simultaneously toggling one of the OC1A pins to generate a square wave. However, we find the I<sup>2</sup>C device constantly throwing errors, and communication breaking up ( though it recovers) when the toggling is going on.

What we are confused about is if the toggling is parallel to the main cpu, as mentioned in the above link, why is it that it seems to be interfering with the I<sup>2</sup>C communication? We thought that this architecture would be better than an interrupt based architecture where the code would break, perhaps in the middle of an I<sup>2</sup>C communication to run the interrupt code. Infact this was the reason we shifted to this mode of toggling the pin.

When the toggling is disabled, the I<sup>2</sup>C communication is happening without any errors.

Any help/explanation would be welcome.

Comment: What are you toggling on and off with the pin, is there a possibility the connected device is interfering? For example if it's something that draws a bit of current maybe the power supply isn't coping, so a circuit might be useful.

Comment: Another possibility: Make sure that the compare function is not being inadvertently configured to generate an interrupt. An unhandled interrupt would cause your AVR to reset, which would definitely interrupt communications!

Comment: Hi, I am toggling a stepper motor driver's input with a square  wave from OC1A. The speed of the stepper motor depends on the frequency of this input square wave. The driver and the microcontroller are powered by the same powersupply which is a 150W computer SMPS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to comment, thus forgive me answering your question. Did you try disabling interrupts by setting or resetting necessary bits on corresponding registers? (For instance TIMSK1 ---> OEIC1A is 0 ) Because it seems that somehow somewhere the timer triggers an interrupt. You can set TIMSK1 bits all to zero, but I suggest you to refer to the datasheet.